# What is the fastest way to insert a new has relation to an existing entry?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I need to insert a finance_entity for each club in a one to one relationship.
I decided to run this in the mysql server, because single inserts are even slower. How could I optimize this to run faster? Is there some way to hack insert select to do this?

I cannot put the club_id on finance_entity, since more then one relation points to it.

```
alter table clubs add column finance_entity_id int unsigned null after id;
DELIMITER !
drop procedure if exists create_entities!
create procedure create_entities()
begin
    create_entities_for_club: loop
        set @club_key = (select id from clubs where finance_entity_id is null limit 1);

        insert into finance_entity (id) value (null);
        update clubs set finance_entity_id = last_insert_id() where id = @club_key;


        if @club_key is null then 
            leave create_entities_for_club;
        end if;
    end loop create_entities_for_club;
end!
call create_entities_for_club()!

DELIMITER ;

alter table clubs change column finance_entity_id finance_entity_id int unsigned not null;
alter table clubs add unique (finance_entity_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a temporary key seems to be the fastest approach.

In addition to this, it's essential for there to be enough size in the buffer, turns out my testing machine only had 16M of buffer size.

Add these to your my.ini or my.cnf

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 512M
```

Use this to insert to the table, adding and index to club_id, might make it even faster.

```
alter table finance_entity add column club_id int unsigned null;
insert into finance_entity (club_id) select id from clubs;

update clubs join finance_entity on clubs.id = finance_entity.club_id 
set finance_entity_id = finance_entity.id;

alter table finance_entity drop column club_id;
```

This ran in 1.6 seconds for 20 thousand entries.

Comment: That is, do all the rows in a single query; don't do a loop around 1-row queries.

Answer (score 0):

If it is 1:1 with an existing table, simply have the same `PRIMARY KEY`, but *without* calling it `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: It can be referenced by multiple tables, a shared key in this case would be confusing.

Comment: @OlaviSau - If the tables are 1:1, then I suggest that having the _same_ key for both is _less_ confusing.  (Or am I missing your point?)

Comment: Is the key the `PRIMARY KEY` in the many tables?  Or simply another column?  Is there really exactly 1 row in each of those tables for a given value of that key?

Comment: Another column, the primary key(finance_entity.id) is referenced in two tables under finance_entity_id. The requirements also changed a bit, currently in the club table, the finance_entity_id is unique ( might change ). The club_member table does not have an unique constraint, since old members are also stored in this table and they have the same financial entity.